# How can I add and track requirements using Jira?

Tags: tracking, jira, requirements

I am trying to use Jira for requirement as well as bug tracking. How do I add requirements into Jira?

Comment: You mean a requirements *issue type*?

Answer (score 0):

My organization uses Issues to track top-level features (usually on support development) and then Subtasks to those Issues for individual requirements.  An Issue might be "Linking not working as intended" with a subtask of "Write a new stored procedure to handle blanks."

For new development, you might check out the Agile module for JIRA.  We have it, but I am not currently on the project that uses it.

Comment: Greenhopper is also another, albeit pricey, option.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious solution is to use "Issue Type" to distinguish Bugs/Requirements.

Or maybe you could try adding a phony version "BACKLOG" where all requirements go first. Then put approved requirements into a planed sprint version (e.g. "R2011-S1"). This is a work-around when you do not have the Agile extension.